# Prevent opening links in a new window (stay in current)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I need to force all links on a page to open in the same window. Is there a reliable userscript that does this?

It would be applied to a web app that handles links using JS. The code is complex (frameworks + proprietary) and I am not proficient enough to follow it and write a tailor-made script that achieves this.

Already searched for solutions in SO, script reposetories and Chrome plugins, but all I could find is popup blockers. However, I need to open the page and keep it in the same window (`target="_self"` if it was plain HTML)

Comment: Here's [a script](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/4416-open-links-in-current-tab) I wrote exactly because the others didn't work. It also sidesteps site's js event listeners.

Comment: @wOxxOm, doesn't work on our app :(

Comment: You need to show [MCVE](/help/mcve) to make this question answerable.

Comment: I understand it may be difficult to answer without MCVE, but the web app is in an isolated environment and I can't share much. As noted in the question, I am not looking for a tailor-made solution, but for a catch-all hack, as the one you attempted to make. Thanks for sharing, though :)

Comment: @wOxxOm maybe I'm doing something wrong, but your script doesn't seem to work here either: http://jsfiddle.net/celohc/yp3okdhe/

Comment: It allows window.open with customized parameters as those popups usually make sense in my practice.

Answer (score 0):

If they aren't explicitly setting a `target="_blank"`, they're probably using `window.open()`. You could try overriding this.

First, check if this is what they're doing by doing this:

```
(() => {
  const originalWindowOpen = window.open;
  window.open = (...args) => {
    console.log('window.open called with', args);
    originalWindowOpen.apply(window, args);
  };
})();
```

If you get something spit out in your console, it means that's what they're using, and you should be able to use this to do what you want (double check the first parameter output in the args is the URL, it should be):

```
(() => {
  const originalWindowOpen = window.open;
  window.open = (...args) => {
    console.log('window.open called with', args);
    location.href = args[0];
  };
})();
```

Comment: Did not work for me:
`// ==UserScript==
// @name GPP no PopUp
// @version 1
// @namespace GPP
// @description Stay in same window for all links
// @include *
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('-----UserScript triggered.');

(() => {

  const originalWindowOpen = window.open;

  window.open = (...args) => {

    console.log('window.open called with', args);

    originalWindowOpen.apply(window, args);

  };

})();

 

console.log('-----UserScript finished.');`
you can find the console output here, maybe there is something useful: https://ibb.co/vdRj92b

Comment: It looks like they may have something tracking that you are trying to stop it from opening in a new window. You'd have to dig into their code really deeply to figure it out. They really want to stop you from doing it...

Comment: You need to add `@grant none` in order to access the window of the page.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm, that helped! Now I get `window.open called with (3) ['', '1_ID_25871649234813020', 'status=1, left=0, top=0,width=1300,height=891']` , so no URL in first argument. What is even stranger is that this ID in second argument is different every time I click on the same link... now what? :)

Comment: I guess the site calls document.write or sets the URL on the returned window object afterwards. You need to debug the code of the site yourself.